# Eclipse CDT: Change Annotation icons on that left bar D: ?

Tags: c++, eclipse, annotations, customization

Hoi.

I love Eclipse. But i hate that huge square annotation on the left, popping up every two seconds:
[image: Image of the annoyance. It is a big orange square with a questinomark inside.]

How can i *change* it? Been able to get rid of it, but I'd like something else than nothing.

(hate squares)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on it -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations.
Here you can configure which icons and where to show.